# Transferring and updating files from local to AWS Ubuntu

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-ec2

So I have been using AWS Ubuntu EC2.

I used scp to transfer files from local machine to remote server. But, when I edited the same files in local machine and transferred them using scp again, the files were not changed in remote server.

```
scp -i path/to/.pem -r /path/folder_name ubuntu@ec2-xx-xxx-xx-x.compute.amazonaws.com:/new_path/folder_name
```

How can I fix this problem? Thanks.

Comment: How about providing us the commands you used so we can help?

Comment: Edited the question.

Comment: scp overwrites files by default, I recommend you check your folder paths correctly, especially the destination directory and ensure you are specifying its path correctly.  One simple test is to temporarily move the file at the destination, run the scp command again and see if the file is recreated.

Comment: I checked the paths correctly. So this is what I did. First, I moved the file to remote server using the commands above. Then, I edited some files locally and used the same command to transfer files to remote server. But, when I check the files in the remote server, they were unchanged and remained the same as the first version.

Comment: You can try rsync as I suggested in my answer below but I'm also wondering if it is a permission issue.  Check the permission of the file on the remote side.

Answer (score 1):

Try rsync instead?

```
rsync -e 'ssh -i path/to/.pem' -av /path/folder_name 192.0.2.1:/new_path/folder_name
```